# Partial Representations in REST API's for collections vs items

Tags: rest, api

I'm putting together a REST based API but I'm not sure on how I should deliver the response for collections vs individual resources.

Does it make sense to have a slimmed down representation for a collection over a single item in the world of REST?

Say I have something along the lines of this for a collection of albums:

```
{
    items: [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Thriller"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

But then for the actual individual item I had

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Thriller",
    "artist": "Michael Jackson",
    "released": "1982",
    "imageLinks": {
        "smallThumbnail": "...",
        "largeThumbnail": "..."
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What do your consumers need?

Comment: Usually to access the individual item your clients will need some sort of key or ID which unique identifies the item. The collection response can be used to provide this. It should also hyperlink to the individual items (HATEOAS) so that the client can simply "navigate" to the individual item it needs from the initial collection response.

Answer (score 0):

A resource representation should be unique irrespective of whether it is given as a collection or a single item. But, you can introduce a new parameter like **fields** which can be used by the clients to get only the required field thereby optimising the bandwidth.

`/albums` - This should give the list of objects each having the structure of what you would give in a individual item api

`/albums?fields=id,title` - This can give the list of objects with just the id & title.