# Restful Uri structure to get array of resources of same type with only limited fields in response?

Tags: rest, api

We have following API to get the list of all versions of cars in our database. A particular version can have multiple colour options available.

```
   GET /api/versions/ 
   [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "colors": [{"name":"red", "hex": "#ff0000"},{{"name":"blue", "hex": #0000ff}}], //array of colors of that version
        "price": 10000
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "colors": [{"name":"red", "hex": "#ff0000"},{{"name":"blue", "hex": #0000ff}}], //array of colors of that version
        "price": 20000
      },
      ...
    ]
```

The client wants an API to get NOT ALL but multiple versions data and only the colour field. What should be the URI for such a requirement? I have thought of something like below but I am not sure:

**To get colors of version id 8 and 9:**

```
   GET /api/versions/?fields=colors&id=8,9
   [
     {
        "id": 8,
        "colors": [{"name":"tui", "hex": "#gg0000"},{{"name":"rie", "hex": #or0000}}], //array of colors of that version
     },
     {
        "id": 9,
        "colors": [{"name":"rie", "hex": "#or0000"},{{"name":"tui", "hex": #gg0000}}], //array of colors of that version
     }
   ]
```

**Please note:** I have oversimplified things here. Versions response is quite complex and contains many more fields other than id, colours and price mentioned above. Plus, we will get multiple such requirements like we have got for colour currently i.e. to get the price of multiple versions.

Comment: What is your issue with this approach?

Comment: No issue I could think. Just wanted to confirm if it's the right way to fetch sub-resources of multiple resources at once OR is there any other better way to do this? Wondering, if it's right, why would anyone create separate API to get different fields i.e to fetch only colors, api like /api/versions/colors - accepting list of version ids

Comment: I think a lot of different approaches are probably fine. You're modifying query parameters, but changing the path to do a separate API is effectively the same from a consumer perspective. It might make a difference from a server perspective, but it will be hard for anyone to give an objective answer to whether this is the 'right' approach.

Answer (score 0):

The query parameters you have specified are perfect!

If you have unique ids for cars which can become a part of your api endpoint like

```
/api/cars/$car_id/versions?fields=colors,price&ids=8,9
```

Or you can try using /api/carversions instead of /api/versions.

You can also refer my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50262429/partial-representations-in-rest-apis-for-collections-vs-items/50265260#50265260)